# regex to match subpattern structure

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm testing out some regex expressions to work with subpatterns so I can aplly through PHP the defined rules for each uri segment. Some of those segments are optional, so I tried this :

```
preg_match('#^/(?P<controller>[\w-]+)(?:/(?P<[\w-]+)(?:/(?P<id>[\d]+)))/?$#uD', '/blog/post', $matches);
```

This regex matches `/blog/post/1` but not `blog/post` as it should, since both the second and third parameters are optional. Any clues?

Comment: Are you sure the 2nd and 3rd groups are optional? I see you're using look-aehead `(?:)`, but to make them optional requires a `()?`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen `?:` is not a lookahead, but a non-capturing group.

Comment: @m.buettner: thanks. I always mix up the various construct names. ;-)  Neither of them is an optional group (`()?`) though, so I got that part right.

Comment: @AndyLester it's not XML

Comment: @AndyLester how is a URI XML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would the second and third part be optional? There is no `?` that makes them optional. The `?` you have is only applied to the last slash. Also, you need to make sure that the third group is still optional if the second one is present. Maybe you were looking for something like this:

```
'#^/(?P<controller>[\w-]+)(?:/(?P<item>[\w-]+)(?:/(?P<id>[\d]+))?)?/?$#uD'
```

Note that in your question the second capturing group was not valid, because you had an opening `<` and not group name to follow. I changed that because I figured it might have been a typo in the question.

It might greatly increase the readability of your code if you took a different approach than regex, though. How about [exploding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) at `/`. Then `$result[1]` would be your controller. Then you could check if there is a `$result[2]` and check that it is a valid "item" (or whatever you call it). And then you could check if there is a `$result[3]`, if that is a number and use it as your `id`. This approach is easily extensible to multiple parameters, and to checking for different allowable items.